# C sharp Text to jpg - how to change image extension

Tags: c#, image

I am using following code to convert text to jpg on the fly.

```
            context.Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
            SaveAsJpeg(bitmap, context.Response.OutputStream, (long)100);
```

When I display the page on the internet images look fine on the surface. But when I right click and **save image** as or **save page as**, I get ashx as file extension.

How can I get **jpg** as file extension?

Comment: Do you save your image to Response.OutputStream as an ImageFormat.Jpeg?

Answer (score 1):

```
context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=your-name-here.jpg");
```

This tells the browser what name the file should be saved as.

Comment: That is not working either. Actually I tried that even before posting this question!

Comment: Could you try it with `inline` instead of `attachment`? I tried that and it worked with both IE9 and FF4.